# Gamepad required - android tv - releasing app

Tags: android, manifest, required, television, gamepad

I have uploaded app on android tv which supports gamepad but it's not required. Unfortunately google play store shows that pad is required. I know it's something with manifest but it looks good to me.

This is important part i guess

> uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gamepad" android:required="false"

Comment: Maybe you are using some library that requires gamepad hence overrides your AndroidManifest?

Comment: In compiled .apk manifest stays like I created it. No changes made by any plugins

Comment: I am facing same issue any updates? i have explore APK for permission using aapt dump badging abc.apk and it shows "uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gamepad" android:required="false" " Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

Since your TV game supports a gamepad but it is not required you should actually exclude the uses-feature for gamepad. Counter intuitively you set gamepad required=false when a gamepad is actually required (game does not work with remote only input).